# Complexity of a non-integer K-Commodity Flow without conservation property

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, directed-graph

I'm working on a problem that can be seen as a version of the Santa Claus problem (defined here for example : https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1132522) where the goods are divisble instead of indivisible.

For the indivisible problem, a reduction to the Partitoning problem is possible to classify it as NP-hard (see [Golovin 2005](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/bde7/b470c35427533949e355f1447bebc85df425.pdf) : page 3). However, with divisble goods, I couldn't find much litterature unless i changed the problem to another form.

The problem can be reduced to the K-commodity problem (an extension of ND38 (from Garey and Johnson) : Directed Two-commodity Integral Flow) with integral flow which is NP-complete, and with non-integral flows it is  poynomially equivalent to Linear Programming (for two or more commodities).

However, the edge that I have in my model wouldn't be conservative as the utility of each resources is not the same for each commodities, and thus, a total input flow flow of 1 unit of commodity i into v doesn't means that the output flow is also 1. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network) it would be defined as preflow because it lacks the "Flow Conservation" property, which is essential in the problem also defined on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-commodity_flow_problem).

Is there a way to prove/explain the complexity class of the K-commodity non-integral flows without the flow conservation property (which my problem can be reduced to) ?

---

To explain a bit more about the problem, i have N employees and M tasks. Each employee i has an efficiency in each task j defined as e_(i,j). The efficiency can be 0 if the employee doesn't know how to do the task. Each employees can work up to H_i hours and can divide his time between the different tasks that he can do.

The objective here is to maximize to production function of the firm which is a [Leontieff production function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leontief_production_function), which is the last done task (the production is a max-min across the differents tasks). There is no collaboration, so the produced task amount is equal to the contribution of each employee (efficiency multiplies by the number of hours passed on this task).

If we think of the task as the agents, this problem can be seen as a max-min utility across tasks (agents) of the allocation of divisble goods (worker hours) with differentiated utilities (efficiencies).

---

As I can't use a linear solver insidemy program, i am limited to finding a good greedy or FPTAS algorithm to solve this within an acceptable margin of error.

Thank you for reading. I would be grateful if you have any idea or general direction/keywords to guide me in my research.